# SQL Cartesian join optimisation

Tags: sql-server

I have a big query for an ETL view that has a cartesian join (see below) which is then left joined to 5 other tables.

```
SELECT W.Field1, W.Field2
FROM   datedim AS d
       INNER JOIN employee AS W
               ON 1 = 1
```

The query takes 5 minutes to run hence I'm trying to optimise it.  The cartesian join is having a big impact on performance.

Any ideas?

-- Additional info

The Cartesian results are then used in an join below.  There several joins very similar to the one below.

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN  detail AS det
                    ON det.id = W.id
                       AND d.datevalue >= det.validfrom
                       AND d.datevalue <= det.validto
```

Comment: You can't really optimize a Cartesian join, but you might be able to optimize the rest of the query that uses it.

Comment: Check the execution plan. Without it, no-one can tell you exactly why this is slow. It may be that you are simply trying to read a lot of data. *Why* are you doing this at all, though? This is the same as `select ... from DateDim, Employee`. What are you doing with this data? And, do you **really** want a copy of `Field1,Field2` for every date?

Comment: Without know what you are attempting to do, it would be hard to suggest any alternatives. Cartesian, or cross-joins, are always going to take a long time, and progressively more time as the tables involved grow. It would be best to analyze what you really need and rewrite your joins to use an index.

Comment: Is there no relationship between these two tables?  Do you really want every single date listed for every single employee?  Can you show some sample input and output to give an idea of what is being done with this data?  My guess is that there may be an alternative to a cross-join.

Comment: This query returns a copy of Field1, Field2 for each date in a date table that may span years. For 100 employees and 10 years, that's 365000 rows, when only a 100 would do. This is most definitely *not* a common scenario for data warehouses or any other form of reporting. What are you trying to do?

Comment: The other joins on clauses are predicated on valid to and valid from dates hence it's important we start with a record that has each date for each employee.

Comment: With a cross-join, all employees will have all dates, it makes no sense if you need to limit employees to ones that have valid start and end dates. Can you provide a simplified version of your tables, and sample content of both?

Comment: The edit doesn't help at all - the cartesian product will still generate duplicate entries without *any date information* - just duplicate rows.  Joining to this will generate duplicate results. Please - provide the table schemas and *describe the actual problem*, not how you try to solve it with a cartesian product.

Comment: The view is being used in a star schema as a bridge table.  What I'm essentially doing is creating facts for people records.   There are no facts in the source hence I have to create them using the data table and various effective dates.